# BackgroundWorker: Pass a generic list to BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, generics

Problem: a method using a generic list takes long to process. Therefore the method should be put to a backgroundworker.

The problem is the following: How can the generic List be accessed from the Backgroundworker?

```
[Call]
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new Tuple<string, int, List<T>>(aInfo, aCount, aGenericList));

...
[DoWork]
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;


            Tuple<string, int, List<T>> aTuple = (Tuple<string, int, List<T>>)e.Argument; // won't work as <T> is not known
...
}
```

I would like to do something like

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork<T>(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e, List<T> theList) where T : Interface
```

but have no clue how this could be used.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You can declare the list as a global variable. Or put it into class scope

Comment: @GianAcuna As global varialbe i would even have the problem how to create it. `private List<T> aList;` won't compile (as T would not be known)

Comment: Somewhere <T> must be known! How is is known when you call RunWorkerAsync()?

Comment: I think the problem is not knowing what type to replace T with.

Comment: We need to see more code. Then we can know how `backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new Tuple<string, int, List<T>>(aInfo, aCount, aGenericList))` is compiling, and make some suggestions.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I would bet that more code won't help.. but.. for example this compiles: `private void Run<T>(String aInfo, int aCount, List<T> aList) where T : IInterface
  {
   if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy != true)
   {
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new Tuple<string, int, List<T>>(aInfo, aCount, aList);
   }
  }`

Answer (score 1):

A common approach to issues like this is to create a non-generic interface that exposes the properties/methods you need from your generic type

In this case you can use an interface to expose the elements of your generic that the background worker is expected to use, say `IListItem`:

You then pass your generic list in as a list of these, casting it on the way in (note that I've also used `IEnumerable` - see below):

```
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new Tuple<string, int, 
        IEnumerable<IListItem>>(aInfo, aCount, aGenericList.Cast<IListItem>()));
```

Note that you need to recast your list to the interface type to pass it through.

Finally, in your `DoWork` method you can now cast to something you know about:

```
Tuple<string, int, IEnumerable<IListItem>> aTuple = 
            (Tuple<string, int, IEnumerable<IListItem>>)e.Argument;
```

I used `IEnumerable` since the `Cast` method returns this type, if you actually need the mutable List in the worker, then the solution will be slightly different (and more messy as it implies you need to start locking the list as it gets changed).

Comment: My problem with the answer: The method is used to transfer objects to another pc by user wish. Before the generic method i had a List<ITransportable> and the problem that on accessing members (as complete objet should be transferred) the members where not all accessible. Therefore that was changed a long while back to the generic method, and in the meantime nearly all interfaces vanished from application.

Comment: What's the transferal mechanism then - maybe you need to serialize your class before you pass it to the worker?

Comment: A method of the object itself is called. The BaseClasses open appropriate WCF-connections and transfer the objects and subobjects (or just a few properties if only properties are changed). And when trying to acces sthe properties with interfaces sometimes some properties were no longer found. (which does not mean that i think that your answer is not correct, it should be a possible way - but I still want to know if there is a way to get a generic in a backgroundworker)

Comment: I suspect its going to involve passing types as parameters,reflection and losing intellisence/the plot somewhere along the way - and then it still won't be quite what you want.